# Test methods for schedular which call the method of external end point

Tags: apex, unit-test, http

I am new to apex and have some questions.

Below are my conditions.

**I have class A_Class in which it calls the external end point in some methods.**

To test this class, I have already written HTTP mock class and succesfully tested.

I have a **schedular class, which calls A_Class to start to run its main method.**

I **want to test that schedular class.**

But when I directly run the schedular with test class, it hits exception because of [TestMethod do not support Web service callouts].

I successfully tested A_Class with HTTP mock class, now I only want to test my schedular whether it is running at sepcific time correctly.

Do I need to comment out the calling of A_Class from schedular when I run test class? If I comment it out, just afraid it gives me problem when I deploy to Production.

How should I approach that kind of situation?

Thanks ahead. Any hints or ideas will be so useful for me.

---Updated (after test)---

```
(main call method)
Map<String,Object> result = new Map<String,Object>();

        if(Test.isrunningtest())
        {
            // Set mock callout class
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Test_Class_Mock_Job_RSS());      
        }

        HTTPResponse res = callOutRssJobFeeds(url);
        result = getJobRSS(res); 

public HTTPResponse callOutRssJobFeeds(String url)
    {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint(url);

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        return res;
    }
```

Now I am getting [System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out] after updated like above and run the test class.

Answer (score 1):

Either set up the scheduler class to ignore the function call while testing (via `if(Test.isrunningtest()) { return; }`, or set up the mock callout, as you did for the other. You may want to just encapsulate the mock callout function in a utility class that contains test methods for testing your code.

Comment: Hi for now, like your suggested (not exactly same though).. I pass parameter (test=true/false) to skip the real call to external point. I will try ur approach. If have issues, I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, can you take a look my updated approach. Now I am getting [System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out] .

Comment: Plus there is no DML statements before the http call out. only getting some values from custom settings.

Comment: Try moving your Test.startTest() to just before you try to schedule/call your class.

Comment: I put  Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Test_Class_Mock_Job_RSS());   between Test.startTest() and Test.endTest().. but only get [Method only allowed during testing] error.